# Passing structure from native C library to C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

I am trying to fill structure containing array from native library to C#.
My structure contains two int variables and array of elements which are structures of two integers.

Issue is that variables inside array are received correctly but variables in the outer structure are received as 0. If I initalize them with different values on the C# side they come unchanged.

**C interface and implementation:**

```cpp
extern "C" {
struct Element
{
    int id;
    int uid;
};

struct ElementsGrid
{
    int width;
    int height;
    Element* elements;
};

__declspec(dllexport) int gridSize()
{
    return 20;
}
__declspec(dllexport) void getGrid(ElementsGrid* grid)
{
    grid->width = 5;
    grid->height = 4;
    for (int w = 0; w < grid->width; ++w) {
        for (int h = 0; h < grid->height; ++h) {
            int index = w * grid->height + h;
            grid->elements[index].uid = index;
            grid->elements[index].id = 42;
        }
    }
}
} // extern "C"
```

**C# part**

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Element
{
    public int id;
    public int uid;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ElementsGrid
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public Element[] elements;
}
//...
[DllImport("my_plugin")]
static extern void getGrid([In,Out] ElementsGrid ptr);
//...
void getGrid()
{
    int field_size = gridSize();
    ElementsGrid grid = new ElementsGrid
    {
        elements = new Element[field_size]
    };
    getGrid(grid);
    print(grid.width);      // 0 here. Unchanged
    print(grid.height);     // 0 here. Unchanged
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
            int index = row * 5 + column;
            Element element = grid.elements[index];
            print(element.id);  // 42. Correct value
            print(element.uid); // ==index. Correct value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# has no shot at guessing how many elements are in the array or how the memory for the array needs to be released.  You can get ahead by declaring the array as IntPtr and marshaling it yourself with Marshal.PtrToStructure() for each element.  Looks like you need to initialize it before the call, use Marshal.AllocHGlobal().

Comment: Make it more efficient with getGridSize(int* width, int* height) and getGridElements(Element* elements) so the C code can write directly into a C# array.

Comment: It's `ref ElementsGrid ptr`.

Comment: @HansPassant C# allocates the pre-agreed number of elements, C sets their values.

Comment: grid->width = 5; certainly does not look like "pre-agreed".

Comment: @HansPassant Apparently the convention is that `grid->width * grid->height` will be equal to the result of `int gridSize()` which C# consults, and the array is 1D.

Comment: @GSerg if changed from `[in, out]` to `ref` it now complains `MarshalDirectiveException: Structure field of type Element[] can't be marshalled as LPArray`.

Comment: It sounds like `getGrid()` is passing a copy of `grid`, and the underlying C# VM then passes a pointer to that on to the C function.  That would explain why the C function's modifications to the array elements through a pointer are visible in C#, but its modifications to the elements of the host structure are not.  But I have no idea why that would be, or how to fix it.

Comment: @uni Add `ref` without removing the `[in, out]`. Also make it `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Element[] elements`... although yes, that's still problematic on the way `out`.

Comment: @GSerg changed to `static extern void getGrid([In, Out] ref ElementsGrid ptr);` still gives the same `can't be marshalled as LPArray` with or without `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]` for `public Element[] elements;`

Comment: I don't think this code can ever run, are you sure you didn't miss any attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally possible, but your code has some flaws. The getGrid method in C++ is expecting a pointer to an instance of ElementsGrid, whereas you're trying to pass the instance, not a pointer to it. The other issue is that the definition of ElementsGrid in C++ differs from the equivalent in C#; C++ wants a pointer to Element, whereas C# has an array of element.

I didn't change your C++ code at all, but managed to get this working as follows.

The structures:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Element
    {
        public int id;
        public int uid;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ElementsGrid
    {
        public int width;
        public int height;
        public IntPtr elements; // Note that this is now a pointer, not an array of Element
    }
```

The getGrid method works when I try it like this:

```
    public static void getGrid()
    {
        int field_size = gridSize();
        ElementsGrid grid = new ElementsGrid()
        {
            width = field_size,
            height = field_size,
            elements = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Element)) * field_size * field_size)  // Allocate enough memory to the pointer for the C++ method to populate it
        };
        IntPtr gridPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(grid));  // Allocate enough memory to a pointer to hold the contents of the ElementsGrid instance

        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<ElementsGrid>(grid, gridPtr, false);  // Fill the pointer
            getGrid(gridPtr);  // Pass the pointer to C++
            grid = Marshal.PtrToStructure<ElementsGrid>(gridPtr);  // Re-assign grid to the contents of the pointer 
            
            Element[] elements = GetElements(grid.elements, grid.width * grid.height);  // Read the array from the grid.elements pointer using the new method below

            Console.WriteLine("Grid Width: " + grid.width.ToString());  // Works
            Console.WriteLine("Grid Height: " + grid.height.ToString());  // Works
            for (int row = 0; row < grid.height; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < grid.width; column++)
                {
                    int index = row * 5 + column;
                    Element element = elements[index];
                    Console.WriteLine("Element id: " + element.id.ToString());  // Works
                    Console.WriteLine("Element uid: " + element.uid.ToString());  // Works
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always clear up the pointers in a finally block
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(grid.elements);  
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(gridPtr);
        }
    }
```

The new method to read the grid.elements pointer into an array of Element. This is necessary as you can't marshall a pointer to an array of structure without reading the array directly.

```
    private static Element[] GetElements (IntPtr elementsPtr, int length)
    {
        int sizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Element));  // Get the size of one Element
        Element[] output = new Element[length];  // Create an array of Element with the right size

        for (int elCount = 0; elCount < length; elCount++)
        {
            IntPtr elPtr = new IntPtr((elementsPtr.ToInt64() + (elCount * sizeInBytes)));  // Read the pointer + offset from the element count
            output[elCount] = (Element)Marshal.PtrToStructure(elPtr, typeof(Element)); Assign the element to the contents of the pointer 
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Also, with a blank canvas, you could achieve this in a totally different way by changing your code in C++ to accept the row and column count and return a pointer to the ElementsGrid struture. The code in C# could pass in the relevent row and column count and read the data from the pointer. That would save creating ElementsGrid in C#, getting a pointer to it then passing this to your C++ code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! it does work indeed. One more question if you please. What is the best approach to use `grid` outside of `getGrid()` function? I think I should crete new C# structure (so it will be two: native and non-native) and return it. So I will be free from manual memory management outside of this function.

Comment: Hi, glad it works :) Yeah you can absolutely create a new structure which has the array of elements without any pointers, you could populate it right after the call to GetElements. From that point on you could free up the pointers and use the new struct to access the height, width and elements array. This approach would lend itself a code refactor, which would let you wrapper the complexity of pointers. i.e. single public static method called GetElementsGrid which just returns the managed struct.